# visibility hidden in AngularJs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

```
<button id="tagBtnId" name="TagsFilter" ng-show="disableTagButton">Tags</button>
```

**ng-show** applied `display: none` or `display: block` property But I want to apply `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` property.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use [`ng-class`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/directive/ngClass) or [`ng-style`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directives as below

**[`ng-class`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/directive/ngClass)**

this will add class `myclass` to the button when only `disableTagButton` is true , if `disableTagButton` is false then `myclass` will remove from the button

expression pass to [`ng-class`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/directive/ngClass) can be a string representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class names to boolean values.

*1 - space delimited class names*

```
.. ng-class="{strike: deleted, bold: important, red: error}"..
```

*2 - an array*

```
.. ng-class="[style1, style2, style3]"..
```

style1, style2 & style3 are css classes check the below demo for more info.

*2 - expression*

```
.. ng-class="'my-class' : someProperty ? true: false"..
```

if `someProperty` exists then add `.my-class` else remove it.

> If the css class name in the `ng-class` is dash separated then you need to define it as string like `.. ng-class="'my-class' : ..` else you can define it as string or not as `.. ng-class="myClass : ..`

[ng-class DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1E0G9Gdh5QK5AU29wSW?p=preview)

```
<button id="tagBtnId" name="TagsFilter" ng-class="{'myClass': disableTagButton}">Tags</button>

<style>
   .myClass {
       visibility: hidden
    }
</style>
```

---

**[`ng-style`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)**

Expression pass the `[`ng-style`][2]` evals to an object whose keys are CSS style names and values are corresponding values for those CSS keys.

EX:

`.. ng-style="{_key_ : _value_}" ...` => `_key_` is the css property while `_value_` set the property value. Ex => `.. ng-style="{color : 'red'}" ...`

> If your using something like `background-color` then its not a valid key of a object then it needs to be quoted as `.. ng-style="{'background-color' : 'red'}"  ...` same as ng-class.

```
<button id="tagBtnId" name="TagsFilter" ng-style="disableTagButton">Tags</button>
```

then your `disableTagButton` should be like

```
$scope.disableTagButton = {'visibility': 'hidden'}; // then button will hidden.

$scope.disableTagButton = {'visibility': 'visible'}; // then button will visible.
```

so u can change the visibility of the button by changing the `$scope.disableTagButton`.

or you can use it as inline expression as,

```
ng-style="{'visibility': someVar ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}"
```

is `someVar` evaluates to true then visibility set to `visible` Else visibility set to `hidden`.

Comment: how I changed "visibility: visible". For that i have to create new class?

Comment: Just set the variable to false, in this way the class is removed

Comment: set `disableTagButton` to `false` then automatically class `myClass` will remove from the button then `visibility: hidden` will remove

Comment: How to set display : block without true false condition? like ng-style="{"someDivId" , 'display':'block'}". I want to do this in the html not the js.

Answer (score 51):

You can use `ng-style`. Simple Example:

```
<div ng-style="{'visibility': isMenuOpen?'visible':'hidden'}">...</div>
```

At runtime, the style changes when `isMenuOpen` changes.

- When `isMenuOpen` is **true**, you'll have `style="visibility: visible"`.
- When `isMenuOpen` is **false**, you'll have `style="visibility: hidden"`.

Comment: How to set display : block without true false condition? like ng-style="{"someDivId" , 'display':'block'}". I want to do this in the html not the js.

Comment: @Milee It's in the html. Example: `<div ng-style="{'visibility': isMenuOpen?'visible':'hidden'}">...</div>`

Comment: you can write : `ng-style="{visibility: isMenuOpen?'visible':'hidden'}"` 
Quotes are only useful with compound words. Otherwise, you can use the CAML syntax for the css properties composed without quotes.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a simple directive that sets the visibility to hidden or visible (but not collapse):

```
.directive('visible', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.$watch(attributes.visible, function(value){
            element.css('visibility', value ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
        });
    }
  };
})
```

Usage:

```
<button visible='showButton'>Button that can be invisible</button>
```

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.directive('visible', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
     scope.$watch(attributes.visible, function(value){
       element.css('visibility', value ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
        });
    }
  };
})

.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.showButton = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
  <button visible='showButton'>Button that can be invisible</button>
  <button ng-click='showButton = !showButton'>Hide it or show it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the directive approach, in this case it might be overkill. But I still like i t :)

Comment: The Angular team should just add a `ng-visible` directive.

Answer (score 13):

Or if you are using bootstrap, use the `invisible` class

```
ng-class='{"invisible": !controller.isSending}'
```

Comment: simplest and most elegant solution, for people using bootstrap that is.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **ngClass** or **ngStyle**, in your case:

```
<button id="tagBtnId" name="TagsFilter" 
    ng-class="{'button-hidden':!disableTagButton}">Tags</button>
```

And this **CSS**:

```
.button-hidden{
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why you not use **ng-if** your tag not render in your html page. I think you use this:

```
<button id="tagBtnId" name="TagsFilter" ng-if="disableTagButton">Tags</button>
```

Comment: This is similar to display;none, but the required style is visibility:hidden. Which is not the same.

Comment: I wanted this ng-if functionality as I wanted to set visibility to hidden and the element should not appear in the html. perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow
the section about Overriding .ng-hide

All you need is to assign the class `hg-hide-animate` to the element

```
/* style your element(s) at least for selector.ng-hide */
/* in this case your selector is #tagBtnId */
#tagBtnId.ng-hide {
  /*visibility:hidden;*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
#tagBtnId {
  /*visibility:initial;*/
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
```

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('app', []).controller('controller', Controller);
  /* @ngInject */
  function Controller($s) {var THIS = this;THIS.disableTagButton = false;}
  Controller.$inject = ['$scope'];
})();
```

```css
/* style your element(s) at least for selector.ng-hide */
/* in this case your selector is #tagBtnId */
#tagBtnId.ng-hide {
  /*visibility:hidden;*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
#tagBtnId {
  /*visibility:initial;*/
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="controller as viewmodel">
  <label>disabled</label>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="viewmodel.disableTagButton" />

  <!-- assign class "ng-hide-animate" -->
  <button 
    class="ng-hide-animate"
    id="tagBtnId" name="TagsFilter" ng-hide="viewmodel.disableTagButton">
    Tags
  </button>


  <pre inspect>viewmodel={{viewmodel | json}}</pre>
  
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```